# LSTM for Irregular Time Series Data with Missing Values

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, lstm

I'm working on a project where I have irregular time series medical data with missing values. I thought of trying an LSTM to impute the missing values. I know it's possible as there are a couple of papers written on it (both LSTM and GRU).

But I haven't been able to find an implementation or at least an example. And if there is something, I don't want to start from scratch. Do any of you fellows have a suggestion or a practical example?

I don't want to impute missing values with mean, mode, or median as it may severely bias the data...

Comment: Can you provide some background on your project? What is the goal of the project? I am reluctant to believe that this is the point of the project and not some tangential adventure.

In any case, have you tried proceeding with the missing data? What are the results? Why is this necessary?

Comment: It is a gas application device for patients in ICU. The purpose is that based on the parameters (features), to predict how much it would consume. However, measurements are not taken at regular timeframes and some logs have empty values.

For example, it has three major outputs, each with its own set of parameters (gas monitor, respiration monitor, va level). 

After combining the logs into one dataset, there are cells with no values, which is what we're trying to fill in. I hope this is somehow more detailed.

Comment: That improves clarity a bit.
What is the target? What are you trying to predict? What are the features specifically? (Just some examples perhaps).
As you have stated, typically we impute mean, mode, or median values for sensor data but this is done to avoid 'biasing' the results.

I have a fair understanding of what you are trying to do. You are effectively creating a sub project which will try to approximate the missing values (predict them if you will). I have worked on something similar with text in the past. Do you have a dataset you will use to validate the outcome of your method?

Comment: What is your justification for LSTM? Have you tried a less computationally intensive method to validate that there is merit to this approach? Maybe a random forest reg/clf or KNN. Use these to validate the method first then proceed to something more complex.

As far as I can tell, no such method exists so you might be working on something novel.